# Visual Studio Code merge not showing me options for a file with local additions and no upstream changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge

I am trying to use the merge feature in Visual Studio code; usually I have been successful. But one conflict in my current file consists of a pure addition in the "local" copy that is not in the "incoming" copy.  I am not given the usual menu at the top of the block where I can choose how to merge this particular item.

One conflict remaining, and I can't find any button to push that would help me resolve it. What to do?  The Complete Merge button is unresponsive.
[image]

Comment: It's not a conflict, right? So there's nothing to resolve(?). Show us what you see in the sidebar. If the file doesn't have "UU", I'm pretty sure that means there's no conflict in it. Just perform the commit to finish the merge.

Comment: No, it's treating it as a conflict and refusing to consider the file resolved. This is the only conflict mark in the entire file, I'm pretty sure I didn't miss one. I had to use the sledge hammer approach to tell git than it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a file before the merge commit, then... just open the file (there's a button to do this at the top right) and change it however you like. There's nothing stopping you from doing that.